# MySQL Stored Procedure Times Out When Called From C#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

`SP_A` is a stored procedure that calls `SP_B`, then does a SELECT, and then UPDATES the same records/column that `SP_B` just UPDATED.  `SP_A` has a TRANSACTION around the SELECT and UPDATE statements followed by a COMMIT.

Now, everything works perfectly when I call `SP_A` from a MySQL command prompt.  However, when I call it from C#, it times out every single time.

The strange thing is, if I change `SP_A` so that it doesn't call `SP_B` and from the C# code call `SP_B` and then `SP_A` separately, it works.  Why is this?

I'm still trying to pin down exactly what the issue is.  It could be:

- You can't call a SP that calls another SP
- You can't call a SP that calls another SP that UPDATES the same records as the callee UPDATES
- You can't do that above when there's a transaction involved

And remember, the problem ONLY appears when running it from C# using MySqlCommand

---

**Note:**
MySql.Data v2.0.50727
MySQL Connector Net 6.2.2
ADO.Net driver for MySQL
.NET Framework 4

Comment: How *long* does it take from the MySql command prompt? If it takes a while (>30 secs) then the default command timeout from ADO.Net will kick in.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the [CommandTimeout](http://mysql2.mirrors-r-us.net/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-commandtimeout) is the issue -> whenver a 'long' query occurs the .NET Connector will timeout.  Increasing the [CommandTimeout](http://mysql2.mirrors-r-us.net/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-commandtimeout) threshold should allow the query/procedure to work.

Note:  The timeout is in seconds.

Comment: The query doesn't take a very long to execute at all. Less than a second